# Copy div from parent website to a textarea in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed, selector, parent

In the Google Translator I've made a second instance of Google Translate with

```
var makediv = document.createElement("secondinstance");
makediv.innerHTML = '<iframe id="iframenaturalID" width="1500" height="300" src="https://translate.google.com"></iframe>';
makediv.setAttribute("id", "iframeID");
var getRef = document.getElementById("gt-c");
var parentDiv = getRef.parentNode;
parentDiv.insertBefore(makediv, getRef);
```

And I'm trying to copy text from auto-correction of the first instance to the textarea of the second instance:
[image]

I'm trying this (this code works if I just copy html within the Chrome inspector{using [0] or [1] to select elements with the same IDs}, however it's only possible to use two instances of the translator with iframe embedding):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var childAnchors1 = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll("#spelling-correction > a");
    var TheiFrameInstance = document.getElementById("iframeID");
    TheiFrameInstance.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("#source").value = childAnchors1.textContent;
}, 100);
```

But the console says that it cannot read property "document" of undefined at eval, and says that the problem is in this line:

```
  TheiFrameInstance.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("#source").value = childAnchors1.textContent;
```

I've tried embedding another website, and it also didn't work. I also tried to call iframe by "iframenaturalID", and tried to write `TheiFrameInstance.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll` without the `contentWindow`, but nothing seems to work. 
I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it work with a different method of creating iframe:

```
var a = document.createElement('iframe');
a.src = "https://translate.google.com"; 
a.id = "iframenaturalID";
a.width = "1000";
a.height = "500";
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(a)
```

And (copying textcontent from the correction div to the iframe textarea):

```
let iframe = document.getElementById("iframenaturalID");
setInterval(function() {
let source = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("source");
let destination = window.parent.document.querySelector("#spelling-correction > a");


source.value = destination.textContent;
     }, 100);
```

Now it does what I tried to do, however I still get mistake message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at eval`, which points at this line: `source.value = destination.textContent;`. It's not a big problem though, but still it's strange that it returns this mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem recently trying to access iframe. Unfortunately it is impossible IF it is a cross-domain. Read more: [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I use the same domain "Google Translate" for iframe. So that shouldn't be a problem, I think. Somehow I get an error that "Execution of script 'CopyingCorrection' failed! Cannot read property 'document' of undefined". I tried what was said in that link...